# Why I can't create firebase user

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

I am trying to create a firebase user, but my code fails, keep getting the Authentication failed message, can you please tell me why?
Also, I don't know how the new firebase is connecting to my account, I used to create a Firebase object and pass my link to it, but now is different, and I can't see where it does it (It asked to login in my webbrowser and that's it, I can't find a reference for it in the code)

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        pass.setText(pass.getText().toString().trim());
        email.setText(email.getText().toString().trim());
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.getText().toString(), pass.getText().toString())
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivityC.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  Did you see firebase console to check whether  user is created or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check below code for your reference.. It will help you.

```
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    String mUserEmail = "sagar@example.com";
    String mPassword = "password";

  mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(mUserEmail, mPassword)
 .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                Log.d(LOG_TAG, getString(R.string.log_message_auth_successful) + " createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
             // if task is successful  then AuthStateListener  will get notified you can get user details there. 
                // if task is not successful show error
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {

                    try {
                        throw task.getException();
                    } catch (FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException e) {
                        // log error here                            

                  } catch (FirebaseNetworkException e) {
                        // log error here  
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                     // log error here        
                     }

                    } else {

              // successfully user account created
             // now the AuthStateListener runs the onAuthStateChanged callback

                }
            }

        });
     }
```